# "400 JSON parsing error" when send post to GCM

Tags: json, meteor

I am using Meteor for sending a request to GCM but I received message

> error: 400 JSON_PARSING_ERROR

I do not understand what is wrong with my code:

```
options = {
  "params": {
    "registration_ids": "def",
    "data": {"message":"abc"}},
    "headers": {"Content-type":"application/json",
    "Authorization": "key=AIzaSyCDCKsZ9BdJie99TC1GCdsZ1kke_oVbzw8"
  }
}

HTTP.call("POST", 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with meteor, but after a quick look at the doc...

What you have under `params` is expected to be request body, so I guess you should use `content` or `data` instead.